# Read Json Log File Continuously and Run Query With Python

Tags: python, json

How can I read this json file continuously (let say last 1 min. logs), and select a specific log information out of the json file (where hostname = wazuh) ?

```
{"timestamp":"2020-07-20T11:35:53.884+0000","rule":{"level":5,"description":"sshd: Attempt to login using a non-existent user","id":"5710","mitre":{"id":["T1110"],"tactic":["Credential Access"],"technique":["Brute Force"]},"firedtimes":477,"mail":false,"groups":["syslog","sshd","invalid_login","authentication_failed"],"pci_dss":["10.2.4","10.2.5","10.6.1"],"gpg13":["7.1"],"gdpr":["IV_35.7.d","IV_32.2"],"hipaa":["164.312.b"],"nist_800_53":["AU.14","AC.7","AU.6"],"tsc":["CC6.1","CC6.8","CC7.2","CC7.3"]},"agent":{"id":"000","name":"wazuh.arge.uno"},"manager":{"name":"wazuh.arge.uno"},"id":"1595244953.11291408","full_log":"Jul 20 11:35:52 wazuh sshd[9453]: Disconnected from invalid user versa
129.204.148.56 port 44580 [preauth]","predecoder":{"program_name":"sshd","timestamp":"Jul 20 11:35:52","hostname":"wazuh"},"decoder":{"name":"sshd"},"location":"/var/log/auth.log"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a little research about monitoring files with python and watchdog module came to my screen, using such module we could monitor if a file changes and we can perform actions over it.
Take a look at this script that I made to your specific use case:

```
import json
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

def on_modified(event):
  with open(event.src_path) as f:
    for line in f:
      pass
    last_line = line
  alert = json.loads(last_line)
  try:
    if 'wazuh' in alert['predecoder']['hostname']:
      print('Is a Wazuh Alert!')
  except Exception:
    print('JSON does not have predecoder attribute.')
    print(alert)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
event_handler = FileSystemEventHandler()
event_handler.on_modified = on_modified
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, 'my.log', recursive=True)
observer.start()
try:
  while True:
    time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

The monitored file is called `my.log`, comparing with Wazuh `alerts.json` each modification of the file is a new alert that we could parse as JSON and detect if there is something that we are looking for.

I hope it helps you, don't hesitate to ask if you have any doubts.

Regards.